# Diferencia de while e if para un bucle

Tags: c++, array, punteros

hice una función que recibe un arreglo  y me retorna el arreglo invertido.Pero para que no me imprima aglo asi : ***5-4-8-6-*** y me imprima algo así ***5-4-8-6*** le agregué un condicional if, me funcionó correctamente y supuse que tambien me iba a funcionar con un while, pero con el while genera un bucle infinito.

¿Porque pasa eso?

```
void invertirElementos(int a[],int tam){//que pasa si no pongo tam
    int *p;
    p = &a[tam-1];

    //BUCLE 1
    
    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
        cout<<*p--;
        while(i!=(tam-1)){
            cout<<"-";
        }
    }

    //BUCLE 2

    /*for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
        cout<<*p--;
        if(i!=(tam-1)){
            cout<<"-";
        }
    }*/
```

Comment: Genera un bucle infinito con *while* porque en ningún momento incrementas la variable `i`, por lo tanto, la condición **siempre** dará como resultado un `true`.

Comment: El ciclo `while` se ejecuta mientras la condición en cuestión es verdadera, si en ningún momento la condición pasa a ser falsa nunca parará.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema esta en lo siguiente:

```
while(i!=(tam-1)){
        cout<<"-";
    }
```

Este `while`, nunca termina, es decir para un valor específico de `i` (para el código que muestras en primera instancia con valor `0` ) nunca cambia. Entonces como el valor de`i` nunca cambia este `while` se ejecuta infinitamente.

Creo que podrías intentar el siguiente código para imprimir en reversa un arreglo.

```
void invertirElementos(int a[],int tam){
    if(tam == 0) return; // si tu arreglo es vacío no podemos imprimir nada
 
    //Ahora que sabemos que no es vacío podemos imprimir en reversa

    cout<<a[tam - 1];//imprimimos el primer valor sin guion
    // Ahora iterator desde el valor anterior al último (que ya imprimimos) hasta el inicio de tu arreglo.
    for(int i= tam - 2;i>=0 ;i--){
         cout<<" - " <<a[i];
    }
}
```

Finalmente, según lo que comentas, **Que pasa si no mandamos la variable `tam`**, bueno en c++ podemos calcular el size del arreglo de diversas maneras, una de ellas es la siguiente.

```
int tam = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
```

donde a es tu arreglo que le enviaste.

Espero te ayude :)